# Ordinary differential equations, stability.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been recently taking a course on qualitative ODE's and stability theory and I am new to these things. I have a problem below.
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x), \ \ \ \ \  x(0)=x_{0},$$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Show that if $f(x_{0}) \neq 0$, then there exists $\delta > 0$ such that the differential equation has a unique solution on $(-\delta, \delta)$.
Any hints or help will highly be appreciable. Does this has anything to do with Lypunov's stability ?????

Comment: Your comment is not clear to me ? After integrating I get $f (x) =C. e^{t}$  do you mean this ???

Comment: Moreover from the initial condition we have  $f(x) = f(x_{0})e^{t}$

Comment: @shaihorowitz: That comment makes no sense at all...

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Lyapunov. The idea is that you can simply solve the ODE using separation of variables (since the equation is autonomous, no $t$ dependence in $f(x)$).

Since $f$ is continuous, it is nonzero not just at $x_0$ but also in some open interval around $x_0$,
and any solution $x(t)$ of the ODE which starts at $x_0$ has to stay in that interval at least for a while. So you must have
$$
\frac{1}{f(x(t))} \, x'(t) = 1
$$
then, which just says that $\frac{d}{dt} \Bigl( g(x(t)) \Bigr)=1$, where $g(x)$ is an antiderivative of the continuous function $1/f(x)$.

Can you continue the argument from there?

Comment: Why $ \frac {x'(t)}{f (x (t))} = 0 $ . Shouldn't there be $1$ on the right hand side. By separation of variables and putting the intial condition I got  $f (x) = f (x_ {0}) e^{t} $. But what I have to do now to conclude the uniqueness ? Locally Lipchitz ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be 1 of course (I've corrected it). No, you don't get $f(x)$ equal to something. The right-hand side $f(x)$ is a *given* function, and it's $x(t)$ that you are seeking. And you can't assume that $f$ is Lipschitz. That's the whole point of the problem, you are only assuming $f$ to be continuous and nonzero. If $f$ were Lipschitz you could just invoke Picard–Lindelöf and be done.

Comment: I got your previous comment to get divide $f$ on both sides on some interval $(-\delta, \delta)$ and get the antiderivative as $g (x) = \ln (f (x)) $. But I am still not able to proceed to find $x $ and also uniquness ????

Comment: No, you don't get $g=\ln f$, that would mean that $g=f'/f$ instead of $1/f$. Your're not supposed to “get” $g$ equal to anything, it's just (by definition) an antiderivative of $1/f$. What you should do is just continue the computation, being careful to argue at each step that there is no *other* solution (since you want to prove *uniqueness*). Like this: if $(g(x(t)))'=1$ on an interval, then we *must* have $g(x(t))=t+C$ on that interval, for some constant $C$. And then, what can we say about $x(t)$? Etc.

Comment: So I can say that since $g$ here is $1-1$,  $x (t) $ is the unique solution.

Comment: Yes, that's it! And $g$ is one-to-one since its derivative $g'=1/f$ is of constant sign (near $x_0$).

Comment: Thank you! It was really nice to listen to you. Hope you have good times :)